# Joining Centos to AD: The directory service was unable to allocate a relative identifier

Tags: active-directory, centos7

Ever since CentOS 7 came out joining machine to AD has been a breeze. It just works, and if it doesn't, the reason is obvious from the error message. However, now I am stuck:

```
# realm join --user=felix@example.net example.net -v
 * Resolving: _ldap._tcp.example.net
 * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: 192.168.1.50
 * Successfully discovered: example.net
Password for felix@example.net:
 * Required files: /usr/sbin/oddjobd, /usr/libexec/oddjob/mkhomedir, /usr/sbin/sssd, /usr/bin/net
 * LANG=C LOGNAME=root /usr/bin/net -s /var/cache/realmd/realmd-smb-conf.R9517Y -U felix@example.net ads join example.net
Enter felix@example.net's password:
Failed to join domain: failed to join domain 'example.net' over rpc: The directory service was unable to allocate a relative identifier.
 ! Joining the domain example.net failed
realm: Couldn't join realm: Joining the domain example.net failed
```

It seems that the culprit is this `directory service was unable to allocate a relative identifier` error; but anything I can find relates to connecting to DC *after* joining.

Domain Controller is Windows 2016 on 192.168.1.50

Interesting (and not surprising, give that domain was successfully discovered), `realm discover` is successful:

```
# realm discover example.net
example.net
type: kerberos
realm-name: EXAMPLE.NET
domain-name: example.net
configured: no
server-software: active-directory
client-software: sssd
required-package: oddjob
required-package: oddjob-mkhomedir
required-package: sssd
required-package: adcli
required-package: samba-common-tools
```

Also, if I use wrong password or use another account that doesn't have join privileges - I get the error that I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pardon, because I'm not super experienced with various Linux distros, but from the Active Directory side, this sounds like you may have a problem with your RID Master. If the pool is depleted and not being replenished, it may be that the other domain controllers cannot communicate with it for some reason.

What happens under the hood is the RID master allocates a pool of (i think) 500 RIDs at a time for new objects, and when that gets to less than half a new request is made and a new block of RIDs is assigned.

I would recommend trying a full dcdiag and looking through it for any errors (or asking your AD admin to do so) as a starting measure.

Comment: *I* am AD admin (it's a small network, a dozen machines / users or so; so I don't claim a lot of experience in it). I ran dcdiag, and the error I see is clearly relevant, but baffling. I'll update original question shortly

Comment: As I look more into AD error that sent me to Event log for Direcory Service, which pointed me to the replication problems... and several KB articles that will take me several days to digest. But this is the answer that started it all!

Comment: Let me know how it goes. I've been down that rabbit hole a few times. I might be able to help you depending on what you see. :)

Comment: DC log shows that it fails synchronization with another DC. The "other" DC is old DC (2012) that I had before I set up this 2016. I demoted 2012; promoted 2016 and turned off 2012. I don't understand why it still tries to synchronize. And your RID hypothesis is pot on. I need to figure out how to stop synchronization; but I won't be able to do that for a few weeks. Thank you :)

Comment: So you've removed the other DC already? If so you need to make sure your FSMOs are transferred to the new servers (seize them) and once you've got them and the DCs all show that, then you need to perform a metadata cleanup on the old object, which will strip it out if it's been powered off or failed. 

Transfer (graceful) or Seize (not graceful, only if other server has failed): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/255504/using-ntdsutil-exe-to-transfer-or-seize-fsmo-roles-to-a-domain-control

Metadata cleanup: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816907(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: additional, would give them an overnight bake in after you seize them over, just to let the rest of the domain sort of work out the kinks, then run a repadmin /replsum and see what you see.

Oh..   in cmd prompt (administrator if UAC etc) 'netdom query fsmo' will report where your DC thinks the FSMO roles are now.

In short, it sounds like the demotion didn't get everything out, or FSMOs were left on the one you got rid of.. maybe the RID master. :)

Comment: I don't have old DC; but I have a backup of the image (it's all VM, anyway). Let me see whether it's easier to "seize", or to restore old DC from backup. My AD administration skills are limited to basic stuff. We don't need any more than that :) "RID" and "FSMO" are new concepts... time to learn

Comment: You won't need it, seize is the operation used when one fails or you plan to never bring it back on, where transfer is if you're doing it gracefully before a shut down/decommission.

To be clear, if you do the seize DO NOT bring it back online if it had roles.

RID = Relative Identifier (the bit at the end of a SID, security identifier)
FSMO = Flexible Single Master Operator/Operations role. These are the 'management' roles of AD that tell the other servers which one is responsible for which function. This replaces the concept of PDC, BDC (primary/backup domain controller) in AD 2000.

Comment: Worked perfectly! As soon as I "seized" RID master I was able to join the domain. Awesome